# Launching debug mode application from c#

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, process, launch

I am currently working on a c++ project and I made a C# wpf launcher to go with it.

**These will work :**

- Visual studio debugger
- Running the .exe in the debug folder
- Running the .exe in the debug folder using window's command line

However starting the file.exe in the debug folder from c# code result in the c++ program crashing on launch. 
I even tried running the same command line in c# that worked by typing it and it result in a crash.

After attaching the debugger to the c++ process the cause of the crash seems to be missing assets (some shader code). However the assets folder is in the debug directory and as I said the program runs by clicking on it.

I have tried in c# :

- Running a command in the command line to simply start the exe
- using `ProcessStartInfo`

What could cause this?

Comment: You'll need to show code. My guess is you didn't set `UseShellExecute` to false.

Comment: And given the error message about missing assets.. I would guess that working directory may not be getting set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Vikas the working directory needs to be set or it seems like windows won't allow the process to access files.

Here is the code that worked for me :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(this.PathToExeTextBox.Text);
startInfo.FileName = this.PathToExeTextBox.Text;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```